# Category Import in Magento without products

Tags: magento

I want to import data related to categories first and then products. But when i am going to upload only category csv file it is showing error "sku not found" and when i am trying to import merged data of category and products csv it is importing products but not showing any category and in products showing 0 record found and in import showing upload success message. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: check if your categories have been imported to relevant site id

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **not** about programming. You should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import categories alone.

Put all information in your csv, then go through a custom script like this one :

(create a script directory in your root Magento folder, and a category.php file in this location).

then you'll be able to import your category by going to yoursite.com/script/category.php

You can find example here :

http://www.magentoworks.net/import-bulk-category-in-magento

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Please refer my tutorial which create category and subcategory using the magento script.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-the-categories-programmatically/

```
foreach ($arrResult as $import_category) {
    try {
        if (strtolower($import_category[16]) == 'true') {
            $enabled = 1;
        } else {
            $enabled = 0;
        }

        if ($import_category[1] == 0) {
            $parentId = '2';
        }
        else {
            $parentId = $list[$import_category[1]];
        }

        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category->setName($import_category[2]);
        $category->setMetaTitle($import_category[2]);
        $category->setIncludeInMenu(1);
        $category->setUrlKey($import_category[10]);
        $category->setDescription(strip_tags($import_category[11]));
        $category->setMetaDescription($import_category[12]);
        $category->setMetaKeywords($import_category[13]);
        $category->setIsActive($enabled);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active anchor
        $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
        $category->setCustomUseParentSettings(true);
        $category->setImage($import_category[6]);
        $category->save();
        $list[$import_category[0]] = $category->getId();
        echo 'Category ' . $category->getName() . ' ' . $category->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Something failed for category ' . $import_category[2] . PHP_EOL;
        print_r($e);
    }
}
```